# Can't get XPath code right in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets, xpath-1.0

I'd start by saying that I have very little knowledge (sadly) of HTML since I do not work in IT. Anyways, I am trying to get the Google Spreadsheet to display data from this website:

http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/2/

I would like to display data from the central table, where results and odds are displayed. I go to Inspect and get the XPath code for this table is:

```
//*[@id="tournamentTable"]
```

But, upon typing it into the `importxml` function, will give me the error

> =importxml("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/2/"; "//*[@id="tournamentTable"]")

After reading here and there on this site, I tried editing the formula and substituting `"` with `'` inside the query, but it gives a blank response.

Could anybody help me?
Am I redirecting the wrong XPath or did I type anything wrong inside the formula?

Comment: This will not work. The actual data is loaded dynamically from a API endpoint.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your answer wp78de!

Comment: Is there any way to make it work even if it has an API endopoint with Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Very well, since my knowledge of the matter is remarkably insufficient, i hereby abandon the issue. Thank you again wp78de.